# multiple display of the same form_widget(form)

Tags: symfony

I would like to display a uniquely defined form_widget(form.myform) at several places in my code. 
How could I do it?
When just put form_widget(form.myform) at different places in my code, only the first one is shown, all the following ones are ignored.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible by following reason: by default twig generates id for each form field considering following scheme - formTypeName_formTypeFieldName, and there could be only one element with such id at the same time.

EDIT:

You could try something like {{ form_widget(form.title, { 'id': 'my_custom_id' }) }} with different identeficators for same field, but those input still will have same names and to be frank I'm doesn't sure how it will be handled by symfony kernel.